# Autocomplete with multiple value

Tags: autocomplete

I am using **autocomplete** which returns ID and Value, when i am selecting the item from autocomplete drop down the ID part, i am saving in hidden field, but suppose if item is there but i am not selecting from drop down simply i am writing whole text into autocomplte text box the ID is not saved into hidden field(it should not be) but i want that so please provide some hint to accomplish that.

```
function AutoComplete(id, url) {
        $(item).focus().autocomplete(url, {
            dataType: 'json',
            parse: function (data) {
                var rows = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].ID, result: data[i].Name };
                }
                return rows;
            },
            formatItem: function (row, i, n) {
                return row.Name;
            }
        }).result(function (evt, data, formatted) {
            $(hiddenfield).val(data.ID)
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo here with Autcomplete with multiple selection.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/jcxbgomd/][1]
```